# How to change the NavBar title color while fetching values from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uinavigationcontroller

I'm fetching the online status from Firebase using a Bool. When the value is fetched, the NavBar title color should change to green or black depending on the status offline or online.

However, when I get the value it's currently changing the title but ONLY after pressing the back button the NavBar title color perform the color change. (I want to update immediately while on the current view, not when pressing back and by the way, the whole hierarchy is being changed, I only want the current title of that view to be changed.

**ViewDidLoad Makes the call**

**Swift 5, Firebase 6**

```
func fetchOnlineStatus() {
        let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
        DB_REF.child("Users").child(user?.uid ?? "").child("online").observe(DataEventType.value) { (snapshot) in
            let postDict = snapshot.value as? Bool
            if postDict == true {
                    navBar?.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.green]
                        navBar?.setNeedsDisplay()
                        navBar?.layoutIfNeeded()
                        navBar?.setNeedsDisplay()
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        self.collectionView.setNeedsDisplay()
                        self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
            } else {
                print("false")
                let changeColor = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.black]
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = changeColor
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change NavBar title color on the main thread:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
    navBar?.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.green]
    navBar?.setNeedsDisplay()
    navBar?.layoutIfNeeded()
    navBar?.setNeedsDisplay()
 }
```

Comment: Didn't work.  btw. I added UIView.animate, same nothing. to your code also added **self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    self.collectionView.setNeedsDisplay()
                    self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()**
same nothing. and it updates the whole hierarchy no only the current view. + after clicking back.